# Error when writing list to text file

Tags: r

I'm trying to write R package bibtex entries to a text file, but I get an error:

```
pkgs <- unique(installed.packages()[,1])
bibs <- lapply(pkgs, function(x) try(citation(x)))
lapply(bibs, write, "bibs.txt", append=TRUE, ncolumns=1000)

Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you even try using write on a single entry that was output from citation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of citation is a list so the error makes sense.  You can use `toBibtex` to get into a format that is more easily handled by `write`

```
pkgs <- unique(installed.packages()[,1])
bibs <- lapply(pkgs, function(x) try(toBibtex(citation(x))))
lapply(bibs, write, "bibs.txt", append=TRUE, ncolumns=1000)
```